# Keep feature branch up to date with develop - Rebasing problem

Tags: git, git-rebase

I want to keep my feature branch up to date with develop branch via git rebase.
What I'm doing:

```sh
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature
git rebase develop
// resolving conflicts
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

And at this step, I have a wtf reaction. I had read a lot of guides about rebasing, but when I type `git rebase --continue` after solving conflicts and `git add .` git shows me this note:

```
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

Then okay, I skipped it cuz I have no other option. After `git rebase --skip` I have the same conflict to solve as before - I'm doing it. then `git add .` then `git rebase --continue` and Here We Go Again:

```
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

Comment: I would guess you are doing `git add .` in a bad directory, different than where the files are. May you send us exact `git status` output before every single git command in your rebase process?

Comment: @RomanPavelka I'm 100% sure that I'm doing `git add .` in the right directory cuz I'm doing it in the root directory of the project.

Comment: OK, then it is strange indeed. Send us those statuses :)

Comment: Git status is clear, how can I have any changes if I'm doing git add .

Comment: Definitely not clear to me. Use `git status` at least before `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: YES. `git status` before `git rebase --continue` shows that I have no changes.